# How many different ways can 64 players be paired?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> Suppose that there are 64 players in an arena. In how many ways can
>   the players be paired up (i.e. 32 different games)?

I think the answer would be:
$$\frac{\prod_{n=0}^{31} {64-2n\choose 2}}{32!}$$

I am not sure if this is a correct expression though, can anyone confirm? If it is, are there any simpler expression than the one I provided?

Comment: Then you would be correct. Nope, I don't think there's a simpler version, not that I know of.

Comment: It is correct. Plenty of other expressions, such as $(63)(61)(59)\cdots(1)$ or $\frac{64!}{32!\cdot2^{32}}$.

Comment: As an aside, convenient notation for $(63)(61)(59)\cdots(1)$ is $63!!$ using [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct, and it is not hard to see what reasoning led to it.  Ideally, the expression should be accompanied by a justification.

There are other expressions for the answer.

For example, let us line up the people in alphabetical order, or in order of height. Alicia can choose her partner in $63$ ways. For each such way, the first person not yet partnered can choose her partner in $61$ ways. And for each such way, the first person not yet partnered can choose her partner in $59$ ways. And so on. This gives a count of $(63)(61)(59)\cdots(3)(1)$. If one prefers (I don't) one can write this as 
$$\prod_{n=1}^{32} (2n-1).$$

Or else line up the $64$ people. This can be done in $64!$ ways.Now partner the first person with the second, the third with the fourth, and so on. Unfortunately this multiple counts the number of pairings.

There are two reasons for this: (i) Any choice of interchanges of $2k-1$ with $2k$, $k=1$ to $32$, gives the same partnerings. To adjust, divide by the number of such possible interchanges, which is $2^{32}$. (ii) Any permutation of the $32$ couples gives the same partnerings. So we must further divide by $32!$. This yields the expression
$$\frac{64!}{2^{32}\cdot 32!}.$$